# iOs recognizing letters, neural network, ocr, etc

Tags: ios

I want to recognize uppercase letters using objective-c.

I have an implementation now that uses tesseract OCR but it's just not accurate enough. The sample size is incredibly small. Only letters A-Z all the same font and all uppercase so there has to be an easier solution.

I'm going to send this to you guys becuase I'm definetly a beginner at iOS. Does anyone know of a way that I can solve this conundrum

Comment: "I'm going to send this to you guys " - erm? send what exactly?

Comment: a bag of cereal and a kungfu panda dvd of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tesseract is probably your best shot. The default OCR isn't great, but you [can train it](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract2) to work better. We [did a project](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQQz3VxJzQo) (skip to 3:25) where we trained Tesseract to read credit card numbers from iPhone images of credit cards.

Comment: I gave up on doing it in the iOS and just went with a neural network over the server.